# What's the difference between sequence preprocessing and text preprocessing in Keras?

Tags: keras, preprocessing, text, sequence

In Keras, we mainly have three types of preprocessing, i.e., sequence preprocessing, text preprocessing, and image preprocessing. However, for me, I think the meanings of the word "sequence" and "text" are the same. How to understand the differences between these two preprocessing operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tf.keras.preprocessing.text` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text)) you have utilities to process **discrete** token sequences, normally used to represent text.

In `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence)) you have utilities to process **both continuous** value sequences (normally used to represent time series) like [`TimeSeriesGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/TimeseriesGenerator), **and discrete** token sequences (i.e. text), like the [`skipgrams` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/skipgrams).

Comment: I think you mean text is just a kind of sequence. So `tf.keras.preprocessing.text` is mainly for preprocessing the text, while `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence` can preprocess other types of sequence.

Comment: Yes, that's it.